# Linux -Bash find, - exec, and sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, find

I am trying to write a .bash script that takes 3 arguments and applies my sed script to the files found that where older than x days ago.

So for example my invocation is:

```
./program.bash <some_path> 2 -r
```

Inside my program I have

```
if [[$3 == -r]]; then
  find $1 -mtime $2 -exec sed -rf my.sed {}/;
fi
```

However my `-exec` connection doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? is there any way to do this without using `-f` and putting the contents of `my.sed` directly on my bash program to be excuted?

Comment: Welcome, there's a syntax error: `[[$3 == -r]]` should be `[[ "$3" == "-r" ]]`. Mind the spaces and quote the strings (or is it a typo?).

Comment: and the end of the `find` command should be `{} \;`, backslash not slash.

Comment: You can use [https://www.shellcheck.net/](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: Yes thank you for all the recommendations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have error in escaping **;** ...

try this... should just work fine

```
 find $1 -mtime $2 -exec sed -rf my.sed {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue!

Comment: Happy to help... cheers!!!!